# Setting icon in Win32 dialog to a default icon

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, ico

I have an icon in a custom dialog box which I would like to be one of the icons which can simply be accessed via macros, such as `MB_ICONERROR` or `MB_ICONINFORMATION`. I know these are of course C(++) macros, so they can't just be writen into the `.rc` file, but I would like to display the file which they correspond to in my dialog. How can I do this?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LoadIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadiconw) function is able to load those standard icons. E.g. `LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_ERROR)` returns the same icon that `MB_ICONERROR` gives you in the standard message box.

To display them in your own dialog box, use a static control with the `SS_ICON` style set, and then use the [STM_SETICON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/stm-seticon) message to assign the icon to the control.

Comment: Thanks, I've got the icon, but I can't find a good example of the use of `STM_SETICON`. How do I send it? When/where?

Comment: @professionalgrammer If your static icon control has ID `IDC_ICON` then, for example, `SendDlgItemMessage(hwndDlg, IDC_ICON, STM_SETICON, (WPARAM)hIcon, 0);`

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect